# Link in comment not displayed/parsed correctly

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks, markdown

I just wrote a comment to an answer and wanted to include a formatted link, but the result was completely broken.

[image: screenshot result]

The link was formatted 100% according to documentation:

[image: screenshot draft]

Can you fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the link text and the link URL swapped. You should use this instead:

```
[SparkFun According to Pete 3-5-12: MOSFETs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFt8hkh17_w)
```

which renders like this:

[SparkFun According to Pete 3-5-12: MOSFETs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFt8hkh17_w)

Comment: Argh, the documentation is severely misleading.

Comment: I don't think so. It's pretty clear that the `http(s)://...` goes inside the parentheses, not the square brackets.

Comment: Well I think so. The `[...]` character pair has more in common with other typical code/text-to-be-parsed character pairs like `{}` and `<>` (e.g. `<title>...`), whereas `(...)` are commonly used in normal text written for literate display. So this sets up the expectation that `[link]` is the http-link while the title goes along in the paranthesis following. Maybe it is only to me this is misleading, but I expect this to apply for other people as well.